# Convert sh+perl script to php script

Tags: php, perl

I've found a coded to retrieve CA certificates. The problem is that the script is .sh format:

```
wget -O - https://eidas.agid.gov.it/TL/TSL-IT.xml | perl -ne 'if (/<X509Certificate>/) {
s/^\s+//; s/\s+$//;
s/<\/*X509Certificate>//g;
print "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n";
while (length($_)>64) {
print substr($_,0,64)."\n";
$_=substr($_,64);
}
print $_."\n";
print "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
}' >CA.pem
```

I'd like to have it on PHP but i don't know how it work in .sh (i use windows and I can't view the output in .sh) so i don't know how to start conversion :(

UPDATE: after some try i'm arrived to this point:

```
$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file('https://eidas.agid.gov.it/TL/TSL-IT.xml');

$content = "";

foreach ($xmlDoc->SchemeInformation->PointersToOtherTSL->OtherTSLPointer->ServiceDigitalIdentities->ServiceDigitalIdentity as $key)
{
    $content .= "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" . PHP_EOL;
    $content .= wordwrap($key->DigitalId->X509Certificate, 64, PHP_EOL, true);
    $content .= PHP_EOL;
    $content .= "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" . PHP_EOL;

}

file_put_contents("test.txt",$content);
```

The problem is that "X509Certificate" is in other blocks inside the XML, so i've to create a loop for every block. Is there a way to extract value only by element name = "X509Certificate" without know the correct tree gerarchy?

Comment: What you posted is not a question, but asking someone to do your work. Try https://perldoc.perl.org/index-language.html and go from there.

Comment: Why not do it correctly and use a XML parser? `curl --silent https://applicazioni.cnipa.gov.it/TSL/_IT_TSL_signed.xml | perl -MXML::LibXML -e '@nodes=XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => \*STDIN)->getElementsByTagName("X509Certificate"); print "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n", join("\n", $nodes[0]->textContent =~ /(.{0,64})/g), "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";'`

Comment: i've update with a partial solution. but i don't how to semplify it. if there a method to retrieve only an element by it's name. BTW the correct url is: https://eidas.agid.gov.it/TL/TSL-IT.xml

Comment: @StefanBecker hi, i'd like to use pure PHP cause the script can run on windows or linux system. So perl can't be executed in an hosted windows server where i can't install 3' party software

Answer (score 1):

Use the [xpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method with a [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) for the node you are looking for:

**EDIT:** just to be on the safe side I added namespace handling

```php
# default namespace for elements without namespace prefix
$xmlDoc->registerXPathNamespace('default', 'http://uri.etsi.org/02231/v2#');

foreach ($xmlDoc->xpath("//default:X509Certificate") as $element) {
```

If you stringify `$element` you should get the text content of the node, i.e. the Base64 string you are looking for.